# Not sure when to use exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

After many years of coding scientific software in C++, I still can't seem to get used to exceptions and I've no idea when I should use them. I know that using them for controlling program flow is a big no-no, but otherwise than that... consider the following example (excerpt from a class that represents an image mask and lets the user add areas to it as polygons):

```
class ImageMask
{
public:
    ImageMask() {}
    ImageMask(const Size2DI &imgSize);

    void addPolygon(const PolygonI &polygon);

protected:
    Size2DI imgSize_;
    std::vector<PolygonI> polygons_;
};
```

The default constructor for this class creates a useless instance, with an undefined image size. I don't want the user to be able to add polygons to such an object. But I'm not sure how to handle that situation. When the size is undefined, and addPolygon() is called, should I:

1. Silently return,
2. assert(imgSize_.valid) to detect violations in code using this class and fix them before a release,
3. throw an exception?

Most of the time I go either with 1) or 2) (depending on my mood), because it seems to me exceptions are costly, messy and simply overkill for such a simple scenario. Some insight please?

Comment: Prevent default construction ? Prevents invalid `ImageMask` instances being created.

Comment: Why do you need a default constructor?

Comment: A default constructor can be useful so you can put objects of that type in certain containers.

Comment: @MadScientist, it may be useful but is incorrect in this case.

Comment: You should throw an exception; it doesn't matter if exceptions are costly if you have a flaw in your program that needs to be fixed. You shouldn't silently return because that hides the error, and you shouldn't do an `assert` because those are compiled out in release mode compilations, and also the client of this class shouldn't need to know what `imgSize_.valid` is since it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @MadScientist: no STL containers in C++11 require that your type is DefaultConstructible.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: asserts are not disabled in release mode. You control whether you want them or not with macro NDEBUG; you can turn asserts off in debug and enable them in release if you want

Comment: You can make a factory function that will always return correctly constructed object. Ie.:ImageMaskFactory::Create(...). It might return shared_ptr<ImageMask>(), other solutions are also possible

Comment: When you say exceptions are "costly, messy, and simply overkill", are you sure they are more costly and messy than whatever other mechanism you propose for handling errors?

Comment: @Andrzej "Release mode" is usually meant as a combination of a high  level of optimisation along with less (or no) debug inforamtion, and disabling asserts.

Comment: @Kristopher: I don't plan on handling these errors. I want it to crash if an error occurs and give me a meaningful message so I can fix it before release. OTOH, when this function is called repeatedly in release code, the check takes some time, and I'm not sure if the throw doesn't leave a footprint as well even if it doesn't actually happen (some exception mumbo-jumbo generated by the compiler inside this function or around it).

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: I think I disagree with this statement "Release mode" is what you want to release to the users. High level of optimization is only one goal for such builds. Another goal is safety measures. Contract violation detection are one such safety measure that you do not want to remove from your program -- otherwise it might enter a UB. What you described are defaults in many IDEs but they would often be overwritten.

Comment: @Andrzej std::array<T, N> requires T to be default-constructible. Using the constructor std::vector<T> vec(99) requires T to be default-constructible, too.

Comment: I do not think it is that bad: when initializing an std::array you can specify the elements explicitly; when initializing a std::vector to a given size you can choose the variant with the initial value: std::vector<T> vec(99, T(...)).

Comment: @Andrzej I think that the point of debug mode is to _discover_ any potential bugs in the program, and release mode is for a program that doesn't have any bugs and you take the debug checking out of to speed execution.

Comment: @Seth: Agreed that debug mode is for debugging. I do not agree with the implication that release mode is free of bugs denoted by assertions. Release-mode program could (or should?) be still prepared for bugs and aborting the program (as assertions do) is a reasonable (though imperfect) default action. My point is that debug mode is a debug mode and NDEBUG macro is an NDEBUG macro. These are two independent things and there is no need to fix one's mind that they should always imply one another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general rule is that you throw an exception when you cannot perform the desired operation.  So in your case, yes, it does make sense to throw an exception when addPolygon is called and the size is undefined or inconsistent.

Silently returning is almost always the wrong thing to do. `assert` is not a good error-handling technique (it is more of a design/documentation technique).

However, in your case a redesign of the interface to make an error condition impossible or unlikely may be better.  For example, something like this:

```
class ImageMask
{
public:
    // Constructor requires collection of polygons and size.
    // Neither can be changed after construction.
    ImageMask(std::vector<PolygonI>& polygons, size_t size);
}
```

or like this

```
class ImageMask
{
public:
    class Builder
    {
    public:
        Builder();
        void addPolygon();
    };

    ImageMask(const Builder& builder);
}

// used like this
ImageMask::Builder builder;
builder.addPolygon(polyA);
builder.addPolygon(polyB);
ImageMask mask(builder);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to avoid any situation where it's possible to create data that is in some kind of useless state. If you need a polygon that is not empty, than don't let empty polygons be created and you save yourself much trouble because the compiler will enforce that there are no empty polygons.

I never use silent returns, because they hide bugs and this makes finding bugs much more complicated than it have to be.

I use asserts when I detect that the program is in a state that it only can be in, if there is a bug in the software. In your example, if you check in the c'tor that takes a Size2DI, that this size is not empty, than asserting if the size stored is not empty, is useful to detect bugs. Asserts should not have side effect and it must be possible to remove them, without changing the behavior of the software. I find them very useful, to find my own bugs and to document, the current state of the object / function etc.

If it's very likely, that a runtime error will be handled directly by a caller of a function, I would use conventional return values. If it's very likely, that this error situation have to be communicated over several function calls at the call stack, I prefer exceptions. In doubt I offer two function.

kind regards
Torsten

Answer (score 1):

To me, 1 is a no option. Whether it is 2 or 3 depends on the design of your program/library, whether you consider (and document) default-constructing image mask and then adding polygons a valid or invalid usage of your component. This is an important design decision. I recommend reading [this article](http://www.synesis.com.au/publishing/quality-matters/exceptions-the-worst-form-of-error-handling-apart-from-all-the-others.html) by Matthew Wilson.

Note that you have more options:

- Invent your own assert that always calls std::terminate and does additional logging
- Disable the default constructor (as others already pointed out) -- this is my favourite

Answer (score 1):

1. "Silently return" - that's real 'the big no-no'. The program should know what's wrong.
2. "assert" - the second rule is that asserts using only if normal program's flow couldn't be restored.
3. "throw exception" - yes, this right and good technique. Just take care about exception-safety. There are many articles about exception-safe coding on [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/index.htm).

Don't afraid exceptions. They don't bite. :) If you'll take this technique enough, you'll be a strong coder. ;)

Comment: Funny that exceptions are so easy and normal to use under Java, while with C++ they are so misunderstood

Comment: Nothing to be surprised. Java manages your memory by itself; Cpp-developer can (and fortunately or unfortunately - must) manage his memory by his-brains. ;)